# jQuery mobile form validation mixed with default messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I'm using `jquery.validate.js` to manage validations in my forms.
In my form I have this line:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" />
```

In this line I have [ `type="email"` ]. So when I try to put a wrong e-mail in this field, the default validation message (in popup) show up. All anothers messages are show `jquery.validate.js` way.

How to fix it?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the browser validation of the new HTML5 form fields (including type=email) by adding the 'novalidate' attribute to the form tag.

e.g

```
<form method="post" action="" novalidate>...</form>
```

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin already does this dynamically by default.  Inspect the DOM on this jsFiddle and you'll see a `novalidate="novalidate"` inside the `<form>` tag:  http://jsfiddle.net/AzJA6/show/

Comment: That's pretty cool. But does that mean you have to mark your email fields as type="text" to make the validate plugin work?

Comment: No... [at least not in my browser; and it looks like the plugin still knows how to take over](http://jsfiddle.net/WhH8a/).  Maybe things work differently when using jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Change `type=email` to `type=text`.  The submission even does not even get triggered because the browser is preventing it due to the `type=email` requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" />
```

It's working in my desktop browser:  http://jsfiddle.net/WhH8a/.  By "working", I'm seeing all messages, including the "email format" message, properly come from the Validation plugin.

The jQuery Validate plugin dynamically inserts a `novalidate="novalidate"` into the `<form>` element, which is supposed to disable HTML 5 form validation.  However, maybe there's some reason why it doesn't work in your Mobile browser.

Since the Validate plugin disables HTML 5 validation, and you want to use the plugin in favor of HTML 5 validation, you might as well remove it from the markup...

... change `type="email"` to `type="text"`.

If you want to use the `email` rule, do it as follows.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // other options,
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            // other rules
        }
    });

});
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/TxN48/**

---

Alternatively, these two rules can be specified inline within the `class` attribute:

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required email" value="" />
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // other rules & options
    });

});
```

**Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TxN48/1/**